# != does not compare Strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code, when I run the code alert shows >undefined< but the if condition is not able to compare Strings.

I put `item.category` in a new `var` but did not help.

```
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
            _create : function() {
                this._super();
                this.widget().menu("option", "items",
                        "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
            },
            _renderMenu : function(ul, items) {
                var that = this, currentCategory = "";
                $.each(items, function(index, item) {
                    var li;
                    if (item.category != currentCategory) { 
                        if(item.category != "undefined"){//it does not work!
                            alert(">" + item.category + "<"); //returns >undefined<
                            ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'><b>"
                                    + item.category + "</b></li>");
                        }else{
                            alert("not");
                            ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'></li>");
                        }
                        currentCategory = item.category;
                    }
                    li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
                    if (item.category) {
                        li.attr("aria-label", item.category + " : "
                                + item.label);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Seems to me that the `item.category` property is undefined (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) as opposed to being defined as a string with the value `"undefined"`.

Comment: `console.log(item.category, "!=", currentCategory)` is? Also the string `"undefined"` is not the same as `undefined`

Comment: @epascarello  undefined != (an empty string)

Comment: Whats the reason for negative vote? I am not a genius to take a guess :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare undefined to a string got with typeof, ill give u an example

```
if(typeof variable === 'undefined')
```

Answer (score 1):

mate, undefined is a type not a string,

```
item.category != "undefined"
```

TO:

```
typeof item.category !== 'undefined'
```

Or:

```
if(item.category)
{
 //code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`item.category` is simply `undefined`. An `undefined` value is not the same as the `"undefined"` string.

```
undefined == 'undefined'; //false
```

However, converting `undefined` to a string will yield `"undefined"`. When you use the `+` operator between a string and any other data type the other data type will first get converted to a string.

`alert(">" + item.category + "<");` is basically the same as `alert(">" + String(item.category) + "<");`

Now, if you want to know if a variable is undefined you may use the `typeof` operator.

```
if (typeof item.category == 'undefined') { //undefined }
```

If you want to check for `null` or `undefined` you may use:

```
if (item.catgegory == null) { //null or undefined }
```